# Interpretation of noun plus like construction

Tags: traduction, anglais, locutions

Je me demande comment interpréter en français les constructions anglaises de la forme : **noun+like**.

E.g., les phrases :

> In general, viscoelastic materials exhibit a combination of **solidlike and fluidlike** characteristics.
>
> A general approach that has been used to address combined **solidlike and fluidlike** behaviors is the theory of viscoelasticity.

je les traduis comme, respectivement :

> En général, les matériaux viscoélastiques présentent une combinaison de caractéristiques de type solide et de type fluide.
>
> La théorie de la viscoélasticité est une approche générale utilisée pour traiter les comportements combinés de type solide et de type fluide.

Est-ce qu'il y a d'autres manières ?

Comment: Il y a deux possibilités; **a)** similar to : [similaire, qui rappelle]  **b)**  characteristic of, typical of : [ caractéristique, *donc* de type ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voici deux propositions :

1.

> En général, les matériaux viscoélastiques présentent une combinaison des propriétés des solides et des fluides.

2.

> La théorie de la viscoélasticité est une approche générique traitant de la combinaison de comportements que l'on retrouve habituellement chez les solides et chez les liquides.